# Fail at startup with latest version

Tags: windows, qbs

I've got a big Qbs project with many dependency on multiple qbs files (on windows 7).

It builds and run fine with Qbs 1.8.

It builds but fail at startup with Qbs 1.10

I've seen that there as been some change in the way Qbs handle dependency in 1.9, but I can't figure out what I should be doing to fix my issue.

I assume that somehow, linking is not done properly with this new version, hence the failure to start the app. I tried running my executable through dependency walker,  but it looks like it finds everything it needs.

EDIT

Startup error in debug mode :

```
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135
```

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible to diagnose with the information you have provided. You'll need to paste the startup error at least. Ideally, you'd also provide a link to the project.

Comment: I've added the startup fail message, but I don't think it will help. The project is not open source, and I cannot legally make it accessible. I'm mainly looking for pointer ans ideas as to how I should approach the problem.